# Wildcard only files with pure make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am seeking for a solution to only match files when wildcarding in make with pure make functions.

Say we have a file structure such as

```
Makefile
dir1/
  file1
  file2
  dir2/
    file3
```

where we want to obtain `file1` and `file2` without any hardcoding, i.e. without explicitly removing or adding files or directories, and where every piece of code is written in pure make. It is okay to assume the depth of the directories.

When writing

```
FILES_DEPTH1 = $(wildcard *)
FILES_DEPTH2 = $(wildcard */*)
FILES_DEPTH3 = $(wildcard */*/*)
```

these expands to

```
FILES_DEPTH1 = Makefile         dir1
FILES_DEPTH2 = dir1/file1       dir1/file2      dir1/dir2
FILES_DEPTH3 = dir1/dir2/file3
```

which is not what we want. While one could solve this problem using `find` as [shown here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189079/446250), I am only interested in solutions that only utilizes pure make functions. Does such a solution exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DIRS := $(patsubst %/.,%,$(wildcard */*/.))
FILES := $(filter-out $(DIRS),$(wildcard */*))
```

(note, not tested...)